# Django ModelForm with Many to Many Field

Tags: django

I have a Django model for a `List` with a many to many field to `Item`, it uses a through table, that has a column for `quantity`.

I want to use Django forms to display a form such that the user can add items to the list. If I just try and create the ModelForm, it shows a selection box, where I can choose items, but there is no way to denote quantity for each item.

I'd like to have it display a dropdown menu where you can select an item, and an input box where you can enter the quantity.

Do I have to do something custom to get it to work this way?

EDIT: I could probably just write the form in HTML myself, but I want to use the validation features of Django forms in the backend too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is an [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) on the *through* table. That would give you the selection box for the item and the input box for the quantity.